# populating a tableview with data using JSON and AFNetworking NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

c & ios n00b here,

I have been working on this problem for 3 days. I am worried that there is a fundamental concept that I am missing. I have researched and and done every tutorial and stack overflow question that relates to this and I can't get an answer. I am trying to populate my tableviewcontroller with data from a json file. I can connect and output from the JSON file but I cannot seem to parse the dictionary and actually use the dictionary. Here is my code that I think is closest to getting it right:

```
TABLEVIEW CONTROLLER
#import "AllTableViewController.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "Beer.h"


@interface AllTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AllTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hopshack.com/db_get_all_beer.php"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject[@"beer"][3][@"name"]);
       NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSDictionary *oneDictionary in responseObject){
            Beer *newBeer=[[Beer alloc]initWithName:oneDictionary[@"beer"][@"name"]];
            [tempArray addObject:newBeer];
        }
        self.beers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Beer"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
    [operation start];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.beers.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"pCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.beers[indexPath.row] name];
    return cell;
}
BEER MODEL
#import "Beer.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

@implementation Beer
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        self.name=aName;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thanks so much guys in advance for your help. this site rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're `self.beers` array is properly populated then I think you are not reloading the tableview.

Add this line after `self.beers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray];`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData]
            });
```

It will reload the tableview after you receive all the data.
If that doesn't work then `NSLog(@"%@",self.beers);` to make sure that self. beers is populated.

I didn't realize it is giving you an error before actually populating the tableView.  I think the problem is that the `name` is returning a `NSString` and not an `NSArray`.  Actually the responseObject contains array of dictionaries so that when you iterate through the array you get a dictionary for each beer.  This way you can just access the beer name with `objectForKey`

```
Beer *newBeer=[[Beer alloc]initWithName:[oneDictionary objectForKey@"name"]];
```

to retrieve the name of the beer.

Let me know if it works out.

Comment: Yan, Thank you for the help, but This threw me basically the same runtime error I've been getting:` -[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cb3b20
2014-06-08 12:34:53.580 HopShack[491:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cb3b20` any suggestions?

Comment: Yan,  Also, stepping through a breakpoint says that my app crashes right when I add the object to the temporary array

Comment: sounds like you don't have a dictionary, you have a string.  Try debugging the data returned in the response.

Comment: Also you can use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to format the response.  This way you will see the type of all the keys a values .